# Where can I find the SXA VariantsController type?

Tags: sxa

I was following the official documentation (https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/18/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/build-a-rendering-that-includes-variants.html) and trying to create a custom SXA rendering with variants.

Everything looks pretty straightforward, we just have to implement different base classes in order to make it work with variants.

The only piece of data that I'm missing is **on which DLL am I supposed to find those variant types** since they are not on `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.MVC`?

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are asking about but there are two DLLs related to variants: `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions`, `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there it is a list of **SXA variants types and their namespace/DLL**.

- `VariantsController`

  - `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Controllers`, `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants`
- `VariantsRepository`

  - `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants.Repositories`, `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.RenderingVariants`
- `VariantsRenderingModel`

  - `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions.Models`,
    `Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Variants.Abstractions`